# Search engine robot.txt

Tags: web, meta-tags

I want to add a robot.txt so my web page can be found...

So I have heard that putting a `robot.txt` with meta tags in the *root* of my site can do this.

- Is this true?, if so,
- What would be the steps to add or generate this robot.txt?

I have found [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/robotstxt.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robots.txt is more for telling the crawlers where to and where to not go *once* they've already reached your site.

A better way to get crawlers onto your site is to build a [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) for your site, then use [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to submit this sitemap to google. You'll also want to include the sitemap on your site's root url and tell google where it is (all of this can be done in Google's Webmaster Tool linked to above).

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't make your webpage suddenly visible. It just instructs web crawlers on how to index your site.

http://www.robotstxt.org/